# Getting Error as "Page doesn't exist -- Enter a valid URL and try again"

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view

I've created a LWC & calling that LWC in Lightning Page, & i'm calling the lightning page on List View button. But when clicked on button getting pop-up as Page doesn't exist. Also i tried to load the page directly in the URL & its still the same.
I've activated the page for all users.

The same this is working as expected in Dev Org.

List View Button URL : /lightning/n/New_Finance_App_Page

Direct URL : https://mandmrealestate--mandmuat.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/New_Finance_App_Page

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up a Lightning page tab for the page you created and use the API name of this tab in the URL for this to work

Go to Setup->Quickfind-> Tabs->Lightning Page Tabs , create a tab for your page here. use this API Name in the url
[image: Lightning Page Tab]
For eg, if your API Name is 'TestAppPage' then put url as '/lightning/n/TestAppPage'

Comment: You are a champ, the issue is fixed.
The tab was created but the api name was different & due to which it was not working. Corrected the name as per your suggestion & it started working.
Thanks brother, appreciate you quick response.

Comment: Happy that it helped 